# How can I know if I need to call setLayoutParams or just change the values of existing LayoutParams?

Tags: android, margin, deep-copy, android-layoutparams

How can I know if getLayotParams() return a reference to the effective params or it's just a deep copy of the params?

say:

```
MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (MarginLayoutParams) getView().getLayoutParams();

layoutParams.leftMargin = horizontalMargin;
layoutParams.rightMargin = horizontalMargin;
```

is enough, or this line is needed as well?

```
parent.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getLayoutParams` returns the actual `LayoutParams`, not a deep copy. However, updating the parameters won't trigger a layout, you would have to call `requestLayout`, which is automatically called when you use `setLayoutParams`.

So if you want to modify the values and have them applied, you need to either call `setLayoutParams` or trigger a layout with `requestLayout`.

If you use Kotlin, you can use the `updateLayoutParams` extension function as well.

Comment: Thanks, how can I see that if you hadn't told me?

Comment: You can check the source code for the View class and check the `getLayoutParams` method.